# C++ 1d line inverse projection onto 2d matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, image, matrix, projection

I have a 2D matrix that represent an image. Firstly, I extract a line from this image (no matter the orientation) and I project pixel's value of this line in a 1D vertical array (with the size of the image's heigth).

This works well. I can perform many operation on this array.

After that, I need to re-insert this vertical array at the same place, same orientation of the line in the 2D matrix.

The problem comes from the inverse projection, I have many holes in my re-integrated line..

```
Mat DataRaw::InsertLine(Mat image_full,Mat image, Point pointH, Point pointL)
{
    float offset = 0;
    float coef_dir = 0;

    // Equation of the line
    coef_dir = (float)(pointH.y-pointL.y)/(pointH.x-pointL.x);
    offset = pointH.y - (coef_dir*pointH.x);

    float x_cur = 0;
    int x = 0;
    float x_prev = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y<image.rows; y++)
    {
        x_cur = (float)(y-offset)/coef_dir; // x courant

        if (y > 0)
            x_prev = (float)((y-1)-offset)/coef_dir; // x à y-1

        x = (int)x_cur;

        if (x_cur-x_prev > 1)
        {
            if (y >= 1)
                image_full.at<uchar>(y-1,x) = image.at<uchar>(y,0);
        }

        image_full.at<uchar>(y,x) = image.at<uchar>(y,0);

    }
    return image_full;
}
```

PointL and PointH are two point where the line passes through. 
I calculate line equation using these two points.

Here is my function to re-insert my line in the 2D matrix, I try to check the difference at each Y step. But...

Thanks for your help !

/***** EDIT ******/

My problem at the left, what I want at right : 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTB0s.png

Comment: Are you using OpenCV? I do not understand your problem... What is your output or error and what do you expect?

Comment: I'm using openCv with Qt, I don't have errors, my problem is when a white segment is in the vertical array, the projection in the 2D matrix appears with hashed segment (like dashed, not continue)

Comment: I edit my post and add a picture. PointH and L are two points where the line passes. 
I calculate the new 'x' in 2D and associate the value of 1d array at the given 'y'.

Comment: I think I understood: your expectation is at right and your result is at left... And you wonder why... I suppose that when drawing you jump over some positions... maybe because of the approximations, but not sure. I suggest you to store Y coordinates (when drawing the line) to see where you loose information (probably in conversion from float to int)

Comment: The line on the right seems anti-aliased.. or at least thicker than 1 pixel in places...